# Ambiguous access of unaccessible virtual function

Tags: c++, inheritance, private-inheritance

Consider this code:

```
struct A
{
    virtual void foo() {};
};

struct B : private A {};

struct C : private A {};

struct D : A, B, C {};

int main()
{
    D d;
    d.foo(); // Error: ambiguous access of foo (is it A::foo(), B::foo() or C::foo() ?)
}
```

The compiler is considering `d.foo()` an ambiguous call although both `d.B::foo()` and `d.C::foo()` are inaccessible and hidden to the user. The only valid call should be `d.A::foo()`, why is it ambiguous for the compiler?

Comment: The name lookup is done *before* access considerations.

Comment: Name lookup comes before accessibility checks